# count number of times aaa appears in a string with and with overlaping

Tags: java, string

Count the number of times `aaa` appears in a string, 1. without repetition and 2. when repetition is allowed. I tried the following code which works well for 1st case but does'nt work well for the second case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="cbaadaaabefaaaag";
    int count=0,count1=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i)=='a' && str.charAt(i+1)=='a' && str.charAt(i+2)=='a')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i)=='a' && str.charAt(i+1)=='a' && str.charAt(i+2)=='a')
            {
                count1++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(str.charAt(i-1)=='a' && str.charAt(i)=='a' && str.charAt(i+1)=='a')
            {
                count1++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count1);

}
```

The input I tried is `cbaadaaabefaaaag` which should give 3 for 1st case and 2 for 2nd case,  also when the input is `aaaa` it should be 1 for 1st case and 2 for overlaping case.

Comment: You should put a little more effort into your spelling and punctuation...

Comment: Is "i/p" supposed to be short for "input"? This is not a chat site, so spell it out.

Comment: You think that works great? Try input with an `a` as the last character: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: yes for small input like 'a' it gives exception because it compares with the next set of character which is actually not present . just came to my mind , but works for little long input.

Comment: In your second case, if input starts with `aaa`, you end up counting it twice, otherwise it does the same as the first case.

Comment: yes i know that why i tried it inside if-else i.e if 'a' at first index it should go inside if block else should go inside else block n compares it with current , previous , next character .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should help you:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String str = "cbaadaaabefaaaaaaag";
    System.out.println(count(str, true));
    System.out.println(count(str, false));

}

public static int count(String str, boolean overlap) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'a'
                && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'a') {
            if (!overlap) {
                i += 2;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;

}
```

The condition `i < str.length() - 2` ensures that you do not get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because if there are only two characters left in the string, there cannot be anther substring `aaa`.

The overlap condition adds two to the current index, where a substring `aaa` was found, so your index points to the next character after the last found sequence `aaa`, which prevents overlapping.

Comment: yes found that while debugging , thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = scn.nextLine();

    int count = 0, count1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {

        if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'a' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'a') {

            count++;

        }

    }

    System.out.println(count);

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() -1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'a' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'a') {
            i += 2;
            count1++;

        }

    }
    System.out.println(count1);
}
```